# My app engine app is not automatically creating default bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My app engine app is not automatically creating  default bucket I don't understand why this is. My other app works fine but when i run the same code in a new app I'm working on it doesn't create the Google cloud storage bucket. Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Deprecated method:** Go to your App Engine Developer console:

https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=s~your-app-id

Then to `Application Settings > Cloud Integration` and turn on the GCS option.

**Current Method:** (Thanks to Grey Panther below)

The old interface has been deprecated. In the new interface, go to:

https://console.cloud.google.com/

Then to `App Engine > Settings` and click on "Create Default Bucket" under "Default Cloud Storage Bucket".  (If the default bucket was already created, it will appear here instead of the "Create Default Bucket" option.)

Comment: Where is that functionality on the new dashboard? Why can't I see that bucket in the new dashboard?

Comment: @ErikAigner As of this writing, there doesn't appear to be a way to set a default bucket in the new Google Developer Console. I can confirm the [Activating GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/activate) instructions still work on the previous Admin console, and pushing `Application Settings > Cloud Integration > Create` correctly creates a default bucket even if you already have a Google Cloud project.

Comment: @duozmo: the old interface no longer works but I posted a reply below about how to do it in the new interface.

Comment: @GreyPanther Good catch. Looks like Google released a new new console.

Answer (score 1):

The old interface (the one indicated by @GAEfan) has been deprecated. In the new interface you can find the option to create the default cloud storage bucket by going to the Google Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com/) and then going to App Engine > Settings and clicking on "Create Default Bucket" under "Default Cloud Storage Bucket".